# With n a positive integer, evaluate the sum?

Tags: combinatorics

I did not quite understand the following question, nor how to evaluate it.

Could anyone assist me ?

With n a positive integer, evaluate the sum :
$$C(n,0) + 2C(n,1) + 2^2C(n,2)+...+ 2^kC(n,k) +...+ 2^nC(n,n)$$

Comment: By $C(n,k)$, do you mean $n\choose k$?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I took this question exactly how it is in my problem set. That's why I am not sure how to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Binomial theorem

> $(x+y)^n=\sum C_n^k x^k y^{n-k}$

Then we have

> $\sum C_n^k 2^k = 3^n$

So we just evaluate $3^n$.

Comment: how did that 3 come about ?

Comment: $(1+2)^n$ using the binomial expansion. I would write $C_k^n$ or ${n \choose k}$ here rather than $C_n^k$

Comment: $\sum C_k^n2^k=\sum C_k^n \times 2^k \times 1^{n-k}= (2+1)^n$ @victor

Comment: You are very helpful. +1 to you.@Henry